# IndentationError: expected an indented block in python error generate at variable scan time

Tags: python

here is my code   actually i want to just use the infinite while loop to scan some int value and perform a compare if to find out the guass number is correct or not but it doesn't work give me the error about "**indentationError: expected an indented block"**

```
running = True
while running:
guess = int(input('Enter an integer : '))
if guess == number:
print 'Congratulations, you guessed it.'
# this causes the while loop to stop
running = False
elif guess < number:
print 'No, it is a little higher than that.'
else:
print 'No, it is a little lower than that.'
else:
print 'The while loop is over.'
# Do anything else you want to do here
print 'Done'
```

Comment: The error says it all: Fix your indentation.

Comment: Python uses indentation to mark blocks of code. Go and have a look at some basic Python tutorials - they will cover this in detail for you.

Comment: I think you should review your [python basics](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/appetite.html).

Comment: In your own words: which lines of the code do you expect, for example, should be part of the loop, and which lines should be after the loop? What **rule do you expect Python to use** to decide that? Perhaps it has something to do with the indentation?

Answer (score 0):

Many languages use braces to to encapsulate branches of conditional expressions, functions, classes, etc. Python uses whitespace to do this instead. Here is the correct formatting for your code:

```
running = True
while running:
    guess = int(input('Enter an integer : '))
    if guess == number:
        print 'Congratulations, you guessed it.'
        # this causes the while loop to stop
        running = False
    elif guess < number:
        print 'No, it is a little higher than that.'
    else:
        print 'No, it is a little lower than that.'
else:
    print 'The while loop is over.'

# Do anything else you want to do here
print 'Done'
```